# php - counter not working within foreach

Tags: php

confused my a lot! here is code. I get 1 for $mc that is a counter! and can not break from foreach loop after 3 times I set.

Code:

```
$mc=0;    
if(preg_match_all('/(\@\`)([^`]*)(`\:)/i', $txt, $matches)) {       
    foreach(@$matches[2] as $m) {
        $mc++;
        if($mc>3)
            break;

    $txt = str_replace("@`".$m."`:",'<a href="profile-'.$m.'">'.$m.'</a>:',$txt);       
    }
}
```

sample text:

```
@`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234
```

Comment: Are you sure you have enough matches?

Comment: Muting warnings is so wrong...

Comment: @Leri And quite unnecessary.

Comment: @putvande I have a lot just test with something like: @`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234
@`test`:
test1234

Comment: @exim could you show us whole codes? What's your `$txt` detail?

Comment: Echo `$mc` and see if you even get to 3.

Comment: I get 1 for all of loop!

Comment: Well.. I guess you only got 1 match so you never get to the `break;` bit.

Comment: Have you debugged `$matches`? e.g. `echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches,true).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you do the replacement separately from the matching process, so multiple identical entries are replaced. Consider using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
$txt = '@`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234 @`test`: test1234';

$mc = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/@`([^`]+)`(?=:)/', function($match) use (&$mc) {
    if (++$mc <= 3) {
        return sprintf('<a href="profile-%s">%s</a>',
            urlencode($match[1]),
            htmlspecialchars($match[1], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        );
    } else {
        return $match[1];
    }
}, $txt);
```

Output:

```
<a href="profile-test">test</a>: test1234 
<a href="profile-test">test</a>: test1234 
<a href="profile-test">test</a>: test1234 
test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234 test: test1234
```

The anonymous function that's used as the second parameter does the actual replacement; it receives the match and should return the replacement string; the `$mc` parameter is passed in via the `use` clause to keep track of how many matches have been handled. After three replacements it will simply return the matched string.

Comment: why str_replace should affect on this variable? I will test your code, thanks

Comment: Because `str_replace('@`test`', 'xxx')` will perform many replacements in your original string.

Comment: I just got it. yes you are right, all tags (@test) are same and get replaced! so code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `$txt` always. You have to merge string with `.=`

```
$string .= str_replace("@`".$m."`:",'<a href="profile-'.$m.'">'.$m.'</a>:',$txt);
```

So like this whole:

```
$mc=0;    
if(preg_match_all('/(\@\`)([^`]*)(`\:)/i', $txt, $matches)) {       
    foreach($matches[2] as $m) {
        $mc++;
        if($mc>3)
            break;

        $string .= str_replace("@`".$m."`:",'<a href="profile-'.$m.'">'.$m.'</a>:',$txt);       
    }
}

echo $string;
```